# Watin - how to test site with popup pages

Tags: automated-tests, dynamics-crm, watin, dynamics-crm-4

I'm using WatiN (Web Application Testing in .Net) to do integration testing on a Dynamics CRM 4.0 website.
CRM uses a lot of popup windows - eg clicking on a Contact in a list opens a new browser window with the Contact's details.

I want to test:

- login to CRM (done)
- go to the Contact list (done)
- click on an Contact, thus trigger the popup (done)
- test functionality within the Contact entity/form (can't do)

So I need to get hold of the popped up window.
How?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't suppose complaining about bad user experience is an option? I don't expect you'll get far down that road though... ;-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
//after the click that opens the popup:    
IE iepopup_1 = IE.AttachToIE(Find.ByUrl(theUrlOfThePopup));
//operate on iepopup_1
```

Answer (score 9):

Syntax has changed slightly in newest version of WatiN (v2.0.20.1089), is now:

```
IE poppedUpBrowser = IE.AttachTo<IE>(Find.ByUrl("http://www.popped-up-site.co.uk/"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe searching for only part of the URL would solve it. This can be done using regular expressions:

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex popupHiddenRegEx = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("part_Of_URL");
IE poppedUpBrowser = IE.AttachTo<IE>(Find.ByUrl(popupHiddenRegEx));
```