# How to Handle File Upload popup

Tags: c#, watin

I'm using WatiN testing Tool I've a scenario where i need to upload a file through the popup window i'm writing scripts in c#.net. when i click on a radio button a popup appears where i need to upload the file and click on the Upload button.Please suggest me some solution.

thankingyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asked and answered here [Watin - how to test site with popup pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657250/watin-how-to-test-site-with-popup-pages)